# How to load swf file by clicking Next button

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash

I was trying to develop courseware using Adobe Flash CS5.5. My courseware has several lesson and each lesson developed in individual flash (`.swf`) file. I've added **Next** & **Previous** button to load next and previous lesson. But, this thing only work if I set **Publish Preview** as **HTML**. Here is the code I've used:

```
function gotoChap1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest ("chap1.html"),("_self"));
}

chap1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , gotoChap1);
```

now, how can I load .swf (or another lesson) file by clicking Next/Previous button when the **Publish Preview** is set to **Flash**? I googled it, but no luck! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a **Loader** instead of the **navigateToURL** function. You can create a Main movie to load each external swf and add in the main stage when the download complete.

Use the following code to automate the process:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// Vars
var currentMovieIndex:uint = 0;
var currentMovie:Loader;
// Put your movies here
var swfList:Array = ["swf1.swf", "swf2.swf", "swf3.swf"];

// Add the event listener to the next and previous button
previousButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadPrevious);
nextButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadNext);


// Loads a swf at secified index
function loadMovieAtIndex (index:uint) {

    // Unloads the current movie if exist
    if (currentMovie) {
        removeChild(currentMovie);
        currentMovie.unloadAndStop();
    }

    // Updates the index
    currentMovieIndex = index;

    // Creates the new loader
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    // Loads the external swf file
    loader.load(new URLRequest(swfList[currentMovieIndex]));

    // Save he movie reference 
    currentMovie = loader;

    // Add on the stage
    addChild(currentMovie);
}

// Handles the previous button click
function loadPrevious (event:MouseEvent) {
    if (currentMovieIndex) { // Fix the limit
        currentMovieIndex--; // Decrement by 1
        loadMovieAtIndex(currentMovieIndex);
    }
}

// Handles the next button click
function loadNext (event:MouseEvent) {
    if (currentMovieIndex < swfList.length-1) { // Fix the limit
        currentMovieIndex++; // Increment by 1
        loadMovieAtIndex(currentMovieIndex);
    }
}

// Load the movie at index 0 by default
loadMovieAtIndex(currentMovieIndex);
```

Dowload the demo files here: http://cl.ly/Lxj3