# Creat a button on the top of loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, button

Im follow this **[How to load swf file by clicking Next button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172555/how-to-load-swf-file-by-clicking-next-button)** and its work.
I have 3 child swf and a "Main.swf" with 2 buttons: "Previous" and "Next" on the top layer. When a new swf is loaded, its on the top op Main.swf and 2 buttons is gone, so i cant click anymore. 
So what can i do to solve? I think i should create a MovieClip, add to a layer below a button's layer then load swf into MovieClip. But i really dont know how to...
Apologized for my English.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `loadMovieAtIndex` function, there is a line:

```
// Add on the stage
addChild(currentMovie);
```

You need to change it to something like:

```
container.addChild(currentMovie);
```

`container` is an instance name of the real container (as you said maybe a MovieClip) which is UNDER your buttons. You can either do this in Flash IDE, or create it via script and swap with buttons:

```
container = new MovieClip(); // could be Sprite or smth like that
addChild(container);

// swaps two children; if buttons are separate - repeat this action for each button
swapChildren(buttons, container);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. The buttons is on the top now. But when i click a next or previous button twice, there is an error:    
**ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at Frame1_fla::MainTimeline/loadMovieAtIndex()
 at Frame1_fla::MainTimeline/loadNext()**

Comment: change `removeChild(currentMovie);` to `container.removeChild(currentMovie);`, where again container is the instance name that you've added and swapped with buttons. What you are doing is making a small wrapper for those clips, and you add/remove children from inside it. So if you add child inside that wrapper, you want to remove the child FROM that wrapper - it's just where it's located.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Its work now...The position of loaded swf if not exactly like a MovieClip (rectangle) i drawn. But i used `container.x = 0` and `container.y = 0`to fix it, i dont know why this happen. Thank you so much. Im happy now.

Comment: Sorry if im bothering you, but i have a problem. Like i said, the position of loaded swf if not exactly like a MovieClip (rectangle) i drawn. But i used container.x = 0 and container.y = 0to fix it. It works. But before a new swf is loaded the rectangle appear (just 1 frame). And because its not fit to stage so its look like a half of stage filled with rectangle. Something like: old swf->rectangle->new swf...Its terrible :(

Comment: What do you mean by 'rectangle'? Is it some kind of rectangle from the new swf that you are loading, from the old one, or it is the background which remains empty while the new swf is being loaded and the old one is gone?

Comment: Its a rectangle (MovieClip) named: "container" i drawn below the buttons. :( and its in Main.swf, which im try to load the others swf (Frame1, Frame2,...)